# Можно ли с помощью айди телеграмм получить актуальный ник?

Tags: php

Есть база данных в которой находятся айди пользователей телеграмм, можно ли как то эти айдишники преобразовать в актуальные ники (использовать в бд сразу ники - не резон, пользователь может его сменить) с помощью php?

Comment: Что имеете ввиду под актуальными никами? Можно просто взять User и к нему добавлять `id`, чтобы получилось, к примеру, `User2342`.

Comment: @Denis640Kb , под актуальными никами я имею ввиду те, которые в данный момент установлены у пользователя, даже точнее сказать теги @ юзер. Мне нужны уведомления приблизительно такие: "Пользователь перешел на страницу" и в этом уведомлении должен быть айди, который взят из базы, преобразованный в тег @ юзер. Вообщем сложно это объяснить, надеюсь понятно

Comment: @Denis640Kb легче будет, если все расписать по пунктам: 1) В базе находится id пользователя телеграмм. 2) В пхп скрипте я достаю это значение и преобразую в тег телеграмм формата @_user (без нижнего подчеркивания). 3) Добавляю это значение в переменную и дальше использую

Comment: Давайте тогда с примером. В базе есть `id = 110` к примеру. Каким образом далее Вы выполняете пункт 2 и 3 . И что хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: @denis640kb в этом то и дело, я хочу узнать, возможно ли это? Допустим id = 110 и юзер с тегом допустим @_user110 привязан к этому айди,  но не его тег, а именно его аккаунт, то-есть при смене тега айди не меняется. Я хочу из этого айдишника получить данные аккаунта и засунуть просто в переменную - все. Такое возможно?